# How do you display fps with opengl es (android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, frame-rate

I am new to java and opengl and still learning so forgive me for my ignorance. I have made an looming object apk file. Now i want to view the fps as the application is playing on my device. I have been following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MYgP8Oj5RY&list=UUKwypsRGgHj1mrlQXhLXsvg&index=67 and attempted to modify it for android but i can't get it to work.

Could anyone show me an example of how to add a simple fps indicator on the corner or on the title page and how to control the fps.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you use this class and call logFrame() it will tell you the fps in a log on your logcat:

```
import android.util.Log;

public class FPSCounter {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int frames = 0;

    public void logFrame() {
        frames++;
        if(System.nanoTime() - startTime >= 1000000000) {
            Log.d("FPSCounter", "fps: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
}
```

from what ive read you optimise your code to get a better framerate by minimising the calls to the gl states

[here is a link for drawText()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370748/displaying-text-like-score-which-changes-on-each-frame/15370887?noredirect=1#comment21730537_15370887)

Comment: is there a way to combine this with drawText() so it is displayed on the glsurface?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but this is Google's first suggestion. So I just want to make it better:

Why count the frames that one second passes? I need in my application a live value of the FPS (as you should use it too). And so far I know it says

```
Frames/Second
```

That means that you can measure the time between one frame and the next and say:

```
Second/Frame
```

To get to FPS it's simply

```
1/(Second/Frame).
```

Here is the code. I used the code from above and edited it to get to my result:

```
public class FPSCounter {
    private long lastFrame = System.nanoTime();
    public float FPS = 0;

    public void logFrame() {
        long time = (System.nanoTime() - lastFrame);
        FPS = 1/(time/1000000000.0f);
        lastFrame = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
....
....
public static int fps = 0;

protected void onCreate(...) {
        ....
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
         fps();
      }
   },0,1000);
}

public void fps() {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
         text.setText("FPS: " + fps);
         fps = 0;
      }
   });
}
```

Renderer method onDrawFrame()

```
MainActivity.fps++;
```